# Systematically update page through AJAX, PHP, and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax

I am trying to update innerhtml of a table "LUpdTbl" systematically based on user input but I cannot seem to parse the JSON data returned at the end.  I promise I've been researching the problem, and I'm sure it's something simple that I'm just not seeing it.

Most of the application is complete except for this one feature that I would really like to present my end users:  The users will make selections on the page and those selections should show up in the innhtml of a table below so that they can make changes to quantity ect.  The part that doesn't work is below:

-> A SQL query is systematically generated based on the User and Work Order they are viewing.

```
var LID = group + WO; //Values obtained from another source
var SQL = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID LIKE '" + LID + "%';";
```

-> SQL statement is passed to SQLGet.php;

```
$.ajax({ url: 'SQLGet.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {SQL: SQL},
    success: function(data) {
    result = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.debug(result);
} });
```

-> The SQLGet.php returns a JSON result

```
$SQL = $_POST['SQL'];
try {
        $result = $mysqli->query($SQL);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }

    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
    $rows = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
        /*I started trying to recreate the multidimensional array before I use JSON.encode but that doesn't seem to make a difference*/
    if ($num_rows > 0) {
            //====================================================
            //  Store results to php variables
            //====================================================
        $LID = Array();
        //...Rest of array removed for berevity

        for($luN=0; $luN < $num_rows; $luN++){
            $LID[$luN] = $rows[$luN]['ID'];
            //... rest of array removed for berevity
    }

        for($al=0; $al < $num_rows; $al++){
            $NLArray['ID'][$al] = $LID[$al];
            //... rest of array removed for berevity
        }
    }
    $post_data = json_encode(NLArray);
    echo $post_data;
         /*I also tried the following instead as well as other options that I've found*/
    //echo 'var NLArray = '.json_encode($NLArray).';';
```

Ultimately, if I can get the results back to javascript in a usable format, I can update the innerhtml but I either come up with an object that isn't an array or an unexpected token error.  I've tried $.map but I get a large string of what seems like functions but nothing that actual resembles an array.

Comment: You're passing SQL statements through AJAX and immediately executing them! No checks, no sanitizing, nothing! Please tell me what site this is on so I can drop all of your tables.

Comment: yeah, this is a really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really stupid idea.

Comment: Also, you've got a parsing error here: `$post_data = json_encode(NLArray);`, you forgot the `$`... `$post_data = json_encode($NLArray);`

Comment: I figured someone would yell about this.  I have a function to sanitize them, I just didn't post it because the code is already long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you are not outputting the correct Content-Type. Try adding the following when you need to do your ajax stuff server side:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Also, I think you won't need the JSON.stringify() call since that would turn your json response into a string (which you would have to parse again if you wanted to work with a json object)

Comment: You can work with your json objects the same way you would work with any object in javascript: using dot notation or square bracket notation like PHP's arrays.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks Adelphia, I missed that $ on my variable. So, with the header('Content-Type...ect) that georaldc posted, I was able to get my object responseText to the data that I was looking for. Looked into using JSON objects, much easier! Thank you guys so much! –